# what is the simplest way to determine (min-s ,max-s) in time T(n)=O(nlogn)? How algorithm works?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The whole scenario is:

Let s=s1,...,sn be a list of integers. Let min-s denote the Smallest integer in S and max-s denote the larget integer in S for all Si E S.

Not using Divide and Conquer explicitly, what is the simplest way to determine (min-s ,max-s) in time T(n)=O(nlogn)? How algorithm works?

Greatful for your help. Thanks.

Comment: You can find the min and max simultaneously in O(n). Why go for O(nlogn)

Comment: Why can't you use an `O(n)` algorithm instead, simply looping through the list and gathering the smallest and largest values at the same time? This would be better than `O(nlogn)`, or am I missing something? If you need find a `O(nlogn)` algorithm then this sort of implies a divide and conquer approach by splitting the workload in ever smaller pieces.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen i have to do with O(nlogn) by not using Divide and conquer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have to compute it in O(n * log(n)) time, you could heapsort the list and take the first and last element. This is a O(nlogn) sort that is not divide-and-conquer.

However, if you just want the minimum and maximum, why not just go for the obvious O(n) solution? Iterate through the list and store the minimum seen so far and maximum seen so far. Replace each if the current number is lower or higher than the min or max respectively.

Comment: yes i have to compute it in O(n * log(n)) time, so can you please tell me how will heapsort work in this matter.  Kindly tell me in detail. Thanks. What if i say you about merge sort for  computing it in  O(n * log(n)) time ?

Comment: @Lawrence Craft Heap sort uses ~1+log(n) for insertion and ~2log(n) for removal so it's not n*log(n).

Comment: Luai, insertion and removal into and out of a heap is O(log n) per element, but you have to insert and remove every element of the set. Hence O(n log n).  Check the Wikipedia article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort

Comment: @Nauman Malik I just saw your comment about MergeSort. MergeSort and QuickSort are both divide and conquer.